# accept argument with object which has a specific annotation

Tags: java, jaxb

**PROBLEM**

If I generate a jaxb object from an XML root element named 'Message' it produces the following class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message")
public class Message{
    ...
}
```

I have a method with the following definition:

```
public void doSomething(Object rootElement) {
    ...
}
```

This method is part of a framework used by 30+ developers. The method only accepts a class with the annotation @XmlRootElement. Developers sometimes miss this crucial javadoc and pass a non @XmlRootElement object to the method giving errors during runtime. As the generated class has no superclass, no interfaces, etc I have to accept an Object as argument.

**QUESTION**

Is it not possible to enforce this check compile time ?

**ALREADY TRIED**

I've looked into (via jaxb binding file) letting generated classes implement an interface and then accept this interface as argument, however it cannot (in an automated manner) be applied to only the root element class.

We have several hundred different XML Schema files from which we generated in an automated manner.

Comment: I think a compile-time check is not possible. So the best you can do is a run-time check and throw an exception if the required annotation is missing.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch That is what we currently are doing, but we want to avoid introducing errors in runtime.

Comment: What tools do you use to generate classes & build/manage project?

Comment: @pirho jaxb to generate classes from xml schema and ant to build project. Why ?